# "Сбыча мечт"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Почему у слова "мечты" нет родительного падежа? И какой аналог тут можно подобрать? "Мечтания" или "желания" - это все-таки не совсем адекватная замена слову "мечты", и, если "сбычу" еще можно заменить слово "исполнение", то что делать с "мечтами" я не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И никто не знает. Это не единственный  случай в русском языке. Так, нет первого лица единственного числа у глаголов "победить" и "убедить". А "сбычу мечт" можно, наверно, заменить "исполнением желаний". Может, кто-то предложит ещё варианты.

Answer (score 4):

Отвечаю на вопросы как они поставлены.

> Почему у слова "мечты" нет родительного падежа?

По фонетическим причинам. "Мечт" затруднительно в произношении (крайняя степень несвободности), других причин нет, грамматически эта форма образуется свободно, семантика не препятствует.

> и, если "сбычу" еще можно заменить слово "исполнение",

Не совсем. "Сбылось" и "исполнилось" - все-таки разные вещи. Точного нормативного синонима, видимо, нет, но в каких-то случаях, возможно, точнее будет "воплощение (в жизнь)", "реализация" и т.п.

> И какой аналог тут можно подобрать

"Исполнение каждой мечты", например.

А вообще синонимический ряд у мечты весьма богат.
Мечта, мечтание, бредни, греза, дума, видение, привидение, иллюзия, призрак, причуда, самообман, самообольщение, утопия, фантазия, химера, воздушный замок, игра воображения, сон, бред, несбыточное желание.

Вот **"воплощение грёз"**, пожалуй, пойдёт.

Comment: Фонетически, слишком близко к "мечеть". Видимо, произошло подсознательное вытеснение нежелательной семантики ))

Comment: Я не согласен с фонетическими причинами-ведь от слова мачты есть родительный падеж-мачт.а замена,по-моему чтобы мечты сбывались.